# Browser giving CORS error in-spite of adding CORS headers in Nginx

Tags: nginx, cors, nginx-reverse-proxy

I've added a host entry for internal IP `192.168.1.119` as `multiserver.billinghub.net` in `/etc/hosts`.
When I visit *http:multiserver.billinghub.net/test/customer-portal* it makes an internal call to `http://multiserver.billinghub.net/jbilling/api/authentication/authenticate` and since the domain is the same the browser doesn't flags the XHR call.

But when I use the IP address instead of the domain name
`http://192.168.1.119/test/customer-portal` the internal call is using `multiserver.billinghub.net` and this is treated as a CORS request and gets blocked by the browser.

I'm using Nginx in the backend for reverse-proxying the request and have added the necessary CORS headers to solve the above issue. Here is my nginx config inspired by this [gist comment.](https://gist.github.com/Stanback/7145487?permalink_comment_id=2824437#gistcomment-2824437)

```
upstream customer-portal {
  random two least_conn;
  server 192.168.1.119:8087;
  server 192.168.1.113:8087;
  keepalive 4;
}

upstream jbilling {
  hash $binary_remote_addr consistent;
  server 192.168.1.119:8080;
  server 192.168.1.113:8080;
  keepalive 4;
}

map $http_origin $cors_origin_header {
    default "";
    "~(^|^http:\/\/)(localhost$|localhost:[0-9]{1,4}$)" "$http_origin";
    "http://multiserver.billinghub.net" "$http_origin"; 
    "http://192.168.1.119" "$http_origin";
}

map $http_origin $cors_cred {
    default "";
    "~(^|^http:\/\/)(localhost$|localhost:[0-9]{1,4}$)" "true";
    "http://multiserver.billinghub.net" "true"; 
    "http://192.168.1.119" "true";
}

## Server block with port and redirect config
server {

  listen 80 reuseport; 
  server_name multiserver.billinghub.net; 
  gzip on;
  gzip_types application/xml;
  gzip_min_length 1000;


  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '$cors_origin_header' always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' '$cors_cred' always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH" always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' "Accept, Accept-Language, Content-Language, Content-Type, authorization, Origin, Referer, User-Agent, Cache-Control, DNT, If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control, Range, Uuid" always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' '*' always;
  
  if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS' ) {
      return 204 no-content;
  }

location /test/customer-portal {
    proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_pass              http://customer-portal;

    # Required for new HTTP-based CLI
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    proxy_buffering off; # Required for HTTP-based CLI to work over SSL
    # set client body size to 2M #
    client_max_body_size 500M;    
  }

  location /jbilling {
    proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_pass              http://jbilling;

    # Required for new HTTP-based CLI
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    proxy_buffering off; # Required for HTTP-based CLI to work over SSL
    # set client body size to 2M #
    client_max_body_size 500M;
  }
}
```

After adding the above configuration I'm still getting a CORS error, for some reason I'm getting multiple values in `Access-Control-Allow-Header` like this
[image]
Can anyone tell me know what I'm missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**
Thanks to my good friend Bharath, who suggested moving the `add_header` directives from the `server` level to the `location` level and the problem was solved.
Since repeating the `add_header` directives were not aesthetically pleasing, I created a `cors.conf` file and included that in my `location` block wherever needed.
**Here's my cors.conf file:**

```
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '$cors_origin_header' always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' '$cors_cred' always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH" always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' "Accept, Accept-Language, Content-Language, Content-Type, Authorization, Origin, Referer, User-Agent, Cache-Control, DNT, If-Modified-Since, Range" always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' '*' always;

  if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS' ) {
      return 204 no-content;
  }
```

**Updated nginx configuration: (excluding upstream blocks for brevity)**

```
map $http_origin $cors_origin_header {
    default "";
    "~(^|^http:\/\/)(localhost$|localhost:[0-9]{1,4}$)" "$http_origin";
    "http://multiserver.billinghub.net" "$http_origin"; 
    "http://192.168.1.119" "$http_origin";
}

map $http_origin $cors_cred {
    default "";
    "~(^|^http:\/\/)(localhost$|localhost:[0-9]{1,4}$)" "true";
    "http://multiserver.billinghub.net" "true"; 
    "http://192.168.1.119" "true";
}

## Server block with port and redirect config
server {

  listen 80 reuseport; 
  server_name multiserver.billinghub.net; 
  gzip on;
  gzip_types application/xml;
  gzip_min_length 1000;

location /test/customer-portal {
    proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_pass              http://customer-portal;

    # Required for new HTTP-based CLI
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    proxy_buffering off; # Required for HTTP-based CLI to work over SSL
    # set client body size to 2M #
    client_max_body_size 500M;    
    include /etc/nginx/cors.conf; # <== included cors-related configurations
  }

  location /jbilling {
    proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_pass              http://jbilling;

    # Required for new HTTP-based CLI
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    proxy_buffering off; # Required for HTTP-based CLI to work over SSL
    # set client body size to 2M #
    client_max_body_size 500M;
  }
}
```

PS: *Building Nginx with the `ngx_headers_more` module as per this ServerFault [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/670632/581357) would have also worked for me.*

**Why was I getting multiple values in Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the first place?**

While making the call from the customer-portal to jBilling, Nginx was adding the required CORS origin header, but when the call was returned from upstream jBilling -> Nginx -> customer-portal

Nginx was adding the CORS header again, hence the value was getting duplicated since the `add_header` directive doesn't overwrite the value if the header exists.
When the `add_header` directive is shifted to the `location` block, as per Nginx we need to manually set all the necessary header values.
I still feel building Nginx with the `more_headers` module is the better way to solve this issue since you get a lot more features with the [ngx_headers_more](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#more_set_headers) module.

##### UPDATE:

I installed the [headers-more-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#installation) and loaded it in my nginx.conf that way I don't have to maintain a separate cors.conf the one I created above and I can set the necessary CORS headers directly at the `server` level.
Here is my updated nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

# Compiled and added headers_more module https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#installation
load_module /etc/nginx/modules-available/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so;

# number of file descriptors used for nginx
# The limit for the maximum FDs on the server is usually set by the OS.
# If you don't set FDs then OS settings will be used which is by default 2000
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;

events {
    worker_connections 4096;
    use epoll;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Updated nginx configuration:

```
upstream customer-portal {
  hash $binary_remote_addr consistent;
  server 192.168.1.119:8087;
  server 192.168.1.113:8087;
  keepalive 4;
}

upstream jbilling {
  hash $binary_remote_addr consistent;
  server 192.168.1.119:8080;
  server 192.168.1.113:8080;
  keepalive 4;
}

map $http_origin $cors_origin_header {
    default "";
    "~(^|^http:\/\/)(localhost$|localhost:[0-9]{1,4}$)" "$http_origin";
    "http://multiserver.billinghub.net" "$http_origin"; 
    "http://192.168.1.119" "$http_origin";
}

map $http_origin $cors_cred {
    default "";
    "~(^|^http:\/\/)(localhost$|localhost:[0-9]{1,4}$)" "true";
    "http://multiserver.billinghub.net" "true"; 
    "http://192.168.1.119" "true";
}

## Server block with port and redirect config
server {

  listen 80 reuseport; 
  server_name multiserver.billinghub.net; 
  gzip on;
  gzip_types application/xml;
  gzip_min_length 1000;

  # Setting Access-Control Headers
  more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $cors_origin_header';
  more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: $cors_cred';
  more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH';
  more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Accept-Language, Content-Language, Content-Type,authorization, Origin, Referer, User-Agent, Cache-Control, DNT, If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control, Range, uuid';
  more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *';

# Allowing preflight request to pass through
if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS' ) {
    return 204 no-content;
}

location /test/customer-portal {
    proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_pass              http://customer-portal;

    # Required for new HTTP-based CLI
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    proxy_buffering off; # Required for HTTP-based CLI to work over SSL
    # set client body size to 2M #
    client_max_body_size 500M;    
  }

  location /jbilling {
    proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_pass              http://jbilling;

    # Required for new HTTP-based CLI
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    proxy_buffering off; # Required for HTTP-based CLI to work over SSL
    # set client body size to 2M #
    client_max_body_size 500M;
  }
}
```